# Trigger Bitrise CI feature branch build on JIRA issue transition to QA lane

Tags: git, continuous-integration, bitbucket, jira, bitrise

I am using JIRA, Bitbucket and Bitrise.io for mobile CI/CD.
JIRA is integrated to Bitbucket, so each JIRA issue is linked to its feature branch in Bitbucket, for example:

Issue - `APPLE-512: Change email in user settings`

Branch - `feature/APPLE-512-Change-email-in-user-settings`

What I would like to achieve is to trigger a Bitrise build when an issue has been moved to QA lane in JIRA, after it has passed the Code Review lane. A standard use case.

So far I have not found a ready solution for integrating Bitrise and JIRA, and thus I am looking for a way to trigger a CURL request on JIRA issue transition but passing along the issue's Bitbucket branch name to the CURL request body proved a bit of a difficult nut to crack. The end result I want to achieve is calling this after an issue transition:

```
$ curl https://app.bitrise.io/app/xxxxxxxxxxxx/build/start.json --data '{
"hook_info":
{"type":"bitrise","build_trigger_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
"build_params":{"branch":"feature/APPLE-512-Change-email-in-user-settings"},
"triggered_by":"curl"}'
```